# Limit of an almost periodic function

Tags: limits, analysis, almost-periodic-functions

Consider the function:
$$
f(t)=\sum_{\nu\in F} c_\nu e^{i \nu t} 
$$
where $F\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a countably finite or infinite set (but $F\neq\{0\}$) and $c_\nu\in \mathbb{C}$.

The question is to give a simple argument which shows that the limit  $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)$ does not exist. A way to proceed would be to prove that $f(t)$ is almost-periodic:
$$
|f(t)-f(t+\tau_\epsilon)|<\epsilon
$$ for any $\epsilon$ and $t$. However I do not see a simple way to obtain this latter result avoiding some theorems and lemmas. Any ideas?

Comment: we're assuming exactly what about convergence of the series???

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: uniform convergence, but let's assume for further simplicity that F is bounded and the sum is finite

Comment: For $F=(-1,1)$ and $c_\nu=1$ the integral is proportional to $\sin t /t$ and the infinite time limit of that certainly exists.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg, I do not understand your comment: if $F=(-1,1)$ and $c_\nu=1$, $f(t)=2\cos(t)$ which does not have infinite limit.

Comment: F is the interval (-1,1) and it satisfies the conditions of the question.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Possibly "the integral is..." would be more clear if you said _what_ integral you're talking about...

Comment: In this case the integral can be defined in the sense of Lebesgue with respect to the natural measure of the interval (-1,1), and $f(t)=\int_{-1}^1 e^{i\nu t}d\nu= 2\sin t/t$. What I'm trying to understand by giving this "counterexample" is why this question is well-founded / interesting. Is $F$ supposed to be a discrete set of numbers? Is there some context I am not aware of?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg I thought it was clear that I am talking about sums not integrals, $F$ is a countably set, $|F|<\aleph_0$, otherwise I would write the symbol $\int$ instead of $\sum$. Of course the claim is not true for integrals. This kind of functions appear quite often in several contexts (physics, signal processing,...), and it would be interesting to have a simple argument which shows they satisfy $|f(t)-f(t+\tau_\epsilon)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: What do you mean by "countably finite"?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey a bounded set with a finite number of elements: $|F|<\aleph_0$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f_N(t)=  \sum_{n=1}^N b_n e^{i w_n t}$$
We find that $$
\begin{eqnarray}\int_{-1}^1  f_N(kt)e^{-i w_1k t}dt&=&
\sum_{n=1}^N b_n \int_{-1}^1  e^{i w_nkt}e^{-i w_1k t}dt \\
&=& \sum_{n=1}^N b_n 2 \frac{\sin( (w_n-w_1)k)}{(w_n-w_1)k}
 \end{eqnarray}$$
As $k\to \infty$ the RHS $\to 2 b_1$, which implies that $$\lim\sup_{t\to \infty}|f_N(t)|\ge |b_1|$$

> If your series $f(t)=\sum_{\nu\in F} c_\nu e^{i \nu t}$ converges uniformly then for any $a$ $$\lim \sup_{t\to \infty} |f(t)-a| \ge \sup_{\nu\ne 0} |c_\nu|$$

Comment: Interesting! Thank you.